# Store content edits in database

Tags: mysql, database, structure

I'm wondering what is the best way to store content edits in a MySQL database?

I was first going to do something like `Current_COMMENT, First_COMMENT` and have the original comment stored in `first_COMMENT` and the latest comment (one that I would display) to `Current_COMMENT`.

But then I realized it would be much better to store each commend edit so I could look back at all the revisions.

My question is, what is the best way to store this in the database? It would be nice if I could store a (almost)infinite amount of comment revisions.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a column for create date, so you can utilize the history if need be. For the most recent comment, mark it with a flag column called `current`. A simple `int` will suffice: `1` for current, `0` for all others.

Comment: Why use a flag column instead of just pulling by max(date)?  If date is indexed it should be about the same efficiency and easier to maintain.

Comment: Because the latest comment may not necessarily be the current one.

Comment: The question asks to display the latest comment as current.

Comment: Problem with a `current` column is that you'd need to do an `update` for the old row before inserting a new row.  Adding some example SQL to do that will improve the answer.  +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @BobDuell I agree, and it's a matter of taste. I'd do it for the sake of future-proofing. The simpler way works too I guess.

Comment: @GordonFreeman One alternative to an extra column is to use a special "high-date" timestamp for the current record (like `2199-12-31 00:00:00`).  Still must update the previously "current" record, but this is how I do similar things.

Comment: I think I will ditch the 'current column' idea as it doesn't seem like a good way to do it. I'll probably just two columns 'comment' and 'datetime' and just display the latest one.